# Is it possible to use heedless charge from shock trooper at a reasonable level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

[The rules I found for Shock Trooper](http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/shock-trooper) state (emphasis mine):

> Heedless Charge: To use this maneuver, you must charge and make the attack at the end of the charge using your Power Attack feat. **The penalty you take on your attack roll must be -5 or worse**. In addition to normal charge modifiers (which give you a -2 penalty to AC and a +2 bonus on the attack roll), you can assign any portion of the attack roll penalty from Power Attack to your Armor Class instead, up to a maximum equal to your base attack bonus.

The way I understand this, you need to get at least -5 to hit from your Power Attack (which means you have a BAB of at least +16). However It seems people are not really considering this point when discussing the usefulness of Shock Trooper, so I am wondering: do I understand correctly this limitation?

Comment: You're quoting a feat from D&D 3.5 edition, in which Power Attack worked differently. In 3.5, you could take a -5 penalty as soon as you had 5 BAB. The sources you mention, are they specifically playing pathfinder?

Comment: I see! I was mistaken because of poorly reading some other question but now that makes complete sense.

Comment: You might consider adjusting the question to accommodate what you now know. I mean, it's reasonable to ask *How can a* Pathfinder *character effectively use the* 3.5e *feat Shock Trooper's heedless charge maneuver, given the changes* Pathfinder *makes to the feat Power Attack?*

Comment: It seems a bit artificial to me. I didn't need to use that feat in Pathfinder, just to understand what some guys in forums were talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shock Trooper is a feat from 3.5 (and not from Pathfinder), and in D&D 3.5 Power Attack doesn't work the same way.

Comment: Perhaps also mention how power attack works in D&D 3; the user can select the attack penalty and damage bonus between 1 and their BAB.

Comment: Yep. Show the differences and this answer will become much better.

Comment: If i were to convert this, i would simply remove that phrase, its unnecessary in pathfinder.